# How come this timer code is saying setText cannot be resolved or is not a variable?

Tags: android, eclipse

```
package com.android.countdown;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CountDownTest extends Activity {

TextView tv; //textview to display the countdown

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

TextView tv = new TextView(this);
this.setContentView(tv);

//5000 is the starting number (in milliseconds)
//1000 is the number to count down each time (in milliseconds)
MyCount counter = new MyCount(5000,1000);

counter.start();

}

//countdowntimer is an abstract class, so extend it and fill in methods
public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{

public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
tv.setText(”done!”);
}

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
tv.setText(”Left: ” + millisUntilFinished/1000);

}
```

Comment: About which line does it say that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're redeclaring 'tv' in your oncreate, so you've not set it as a new textView. Change this line:

```
 TextView tv = new TextView(this);
```

into

```
 tv = new TextView(this);
```

edit:
Another problem: you hav a separate counter class. That class cannot access the properties of your countDownTest activity. So the "tv" variable is empty there. You cannot just have a random subclass use the vars of your superclass. 
I think you should go back to the design of your classes, and figure out what goes where?

In the meantime, if you're just testing, you could do something like this:

give your textview an id (with `setId()` i think).
Get your textview using `findViewById()` in your mycount class.
Use that to change the text.

or

Add a memeber to your MyCount that has a parameter "textview", and call that with your origional tv var.

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to mention that is the way I originally had it. It still has the same error

Answer (score 0):

nanne is right just delete type before this line tv = new TextView(this);

However that is the only change yo need to make because your class is an inner class of this activity and you have defined tv to be a varibale for all activity which includes all methods and inner classes in it.

With that change this code works, I've just tested it.

But if your MyCount file is in a separate .java file, then you need to pass this view like this:

MyCount counter = new MyCount(5000,1000, tv);

end MyCount class would look like this:

```
    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{  
TextView tv;  

public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval, TextView tvx) {  
super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);  
tv = tvx;
}  

@Override  
public void onFinish() {  
tv.setText("done!");  
}  

@Override  
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {  
tv.setText("Left: " + millisUntilFinished/1000);  

}}
```